# How does the natural filtration of a Brownian motion look like?

Tags: measure-theory, brownian-motion

I am trying to understand how the natural filtration for a Brownian motion might look like.

**Definitions:** 
I will start with the definitions for reference. The definition of a natural filtration is
$$\mathcal{F}^W(t) = \sigma(\{W_s; 0\le s \le t\}),\quad\text{for all } t\in [0,T].$$
Where for a subset $\mathcal{M}\in \mathcal{P}(\Omega)$ the $\sigma$-Operator is defined as
$$\sigma(\mathcal{M})=\bigcap_{\mathcal{A}\in\mathcal{F}(\mathcal{M})}\mathcal{A}.$$
Finally, $\mathcal{F}(M)$ is the set of all $\sigma$-Algebras which contain $\mathcal{M}$:
$$\mathcal{F}(M)=\{\mathcal{A} \subseteq \mathcal{P}(\Omega)|\mathcal{M}\subseteq\mathcal{A}, \mathcal{A}\text{ is }\sigma\text{-Algebra}\}$$

**Question:**
How does the natural filtration of a Brownian motion look like?

---

The concept is still fuzzy to me, so I can't formulate the question as one single statement, but here are the points I find puzzling:

- Is the intuitive idea correct that the $\sigma$-Operator makes all the sub-sections of the path of the Brownian motion also measurable?
- Why then do I need to bring in the set of all possible $\sigma$-Algebras into the definition, why isn't it possible to define the measurable sets by intersections of my original $\{W(s); 0\le s \le t\}$?

---

Here are related questions for further reference:

- [Definition of the Brownian motion](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/110891/definition-of-the-brownian-motion?rq=1)
- [sigma algebra stochastic process](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/10529/sigma-algebra-stochastic-process/10548#10548)
- [$\sigma$-algebra generated by Brownian motion](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/145824/sigma-algebra-generated-by-brownian-motion)
- [Random walk as a martingale?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/419190/random-walk-as-a-martingale/419248#419248)
- [Brownian motion and adapted](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/505724/brownian-motion-and-adapted/505745#505745)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically you are confusing two notations here. In fact,
$\mathcal F^W(t)$ is the smallest sigma-algebra which contains every event $\{W_s\in B\}$ with $s$ in $[0,t]$ and $B$ in $\mathcal B(\mathbb R)$.

The smallest sigma-algebra which contains every event $\{X\in B\}$ with $X$ in some collection of random variables $\mathcal X$ and $B$ in $\mathcal B(\mathbb R)$ is often denoted $\sigma(\mathcal X)$, in your case $\mathcal X$ is the collection $\mathcal X=\{W_s\,;\,0\leqslant s\leqslant t)$. Finally, recall that 
$\{X\in B\}$ is a notation for $\{X\in B\}=X^{-1}(B)$.

Comment: $\mathcal F^W(t)$ contains no path, it contains only *events*. Roughly speaking, an event is in $\mathcal F^W(t)$ if it depends only on $(W_s)_{s\leqslant t}$.